# Import csv into python and sum the row of numbers

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have started learning python with great enthusiasm and managed to get through the procedures, functions and bit of lists. And feel ready to take the learning forward by building a useful application.

I would like the user to export an excel file into csv with just one row of numbers, some of them negative, positive and zeros. And want to calculate the average of positive numbers and average of negative numbers.

The calculating bit isn't the problem, its the importing csv bit. I've been reading the python documentation but looked confusing.

Please get me started on importing a csv file and summing the row of numbers. Thank you!

Comment: CSV importing, exporing, and processing is built into Python. See [the docs for the CSV module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

Comment: Please show an example csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started.

```
import csv

with open("file.csv", "rb") as ins:
    for row in csv.reader(ins):
        print sum(map(int, row))
```

The [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) is a way to make this exception-safe.  In most cases, the following is good enough:

```
import csv

ins = open("file.csv", "rb")
for row in csv.reader(ins):
    print sum(map(int, row))
ins.close()
```

The above solutions don't work with Python 3.  Instead, try this:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", "r") as ins:
    for row in csv.reader(ins):
        print(sum(map(int, row)))
```

Comment: sorry, thats a bit too advance for me, especially the "with" statement, also "ins" ? Thanks.

Comment: @user1419509 `ins` is a variable holding a `file` object.

Comment: @user1419509 Just in case you are curious about the `with` statement, this may help: http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example

Comment: Relying on handles being closed by removing references to them is really not very good practice; it'll lead to different behavior in non-ref-counted Pythons like PyPy, for example. `ins.close()` is easier to understand and more correct. (Of course, the `with` statement is still the best approach.)

Comment: @Dougal fixed, but I definitely recommended `with` over that anyway.

Comment: @user1419509 is this what you wanted?

Comment: yes, thank you. can you explain the "rb" and the ins.close() ?

Comment: @user1419509 `rb` is the mode to for opening the file, i.e., read in binary mode. `ins.close()` closes your file. If the above question answered your question consider marking it as accepted with the checkmark next to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770101/import-csv-into-python-and-sum-the-row-of-numbers#10770119

Comment: I'm getting this error message - iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: @user1419509 change `"rb"` to `"r"`.  Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: i am using 3, and changing to "r" seems to work but its giving me the rows without summing. Is this to do with using python 3 again ?